# Make directory system from user id in python list

Tags: python, list, directory

Please help!

Well, first of all, I will explain what this should do. I'm trying to store users and servers from discord in a list (users that use the bot and servers in which the bot is in) with the id.

for example:

```
class User(object):
  name = ""
  uid = 0
```

Now, all discord id are very long and I want to store lots of users and servers in my list (one list for each one) but suppose that I get 10.000 users in my list, and I want to get the last one (without knowing it's the last one), this would take a lot of time. Instead, I thought that I could make a directory system for storing users in the list and finding it quickly. This is how it works:

I can get the id easily so imagine my id is `12345`.
Now I convert it into a string using python `str(id)` function and I store it in a variable, `strId`.
For each digit of the list, I use it as an index for the users list, like this:

*The `User()` is where the user is stored*

```
users_list = [[[], [[], [], [[], [], [], [User()]]]]]
actual_dir = 0
for digit in strId:
  actual_dir = digit

user = actual_dir[0]
```

And that's how I reach the user (or something like that)

Now, here is where my problem is. I know I can get the user easily by getting the user by id, but when I want to save the changes, I should do something like `users_list[1][2][3][4][5] = changed_user_variable`, but how far I know I cannot do something like `list[1] += [2]`

Is there any way to reach the user and save the changes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a python dictionary with the user id as the key and the user object as the value. I ran a test on my own computer and found that finding 100 000 random users in a dictionary with 10 million users only took 0.3s. This method is much simpler and I would guess it's just as fast, if not faster.

You can create a dictionary and add users with:

```
users = {}

users[userID] = some_user
```

(many other ways of doing this)

by using a dictionary you can easily change a user's field by:

```
users[userID].some_field = "Some value"
```

or overwrite the same way you add users in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I had done it at the start, but i'm using repl.it and i got an error that told me that the dictionary was not json serializable. Now, for some reason, the error has gone.